# Controllers as syntax in Mean

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have read about `Controller As` syntax (i.e. http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) and it seems to be a good choice when using Angular.
I also tried mean.js (http://meanjs.org/) but they do not implement it in their templates, if I am correct. I am new to Mean and would like to study the templates, something similar to what mean.js provides. Could anyone recommend some substitute to mean.js, which uses `Controller As`syntax?
Best Regards

Comment: MEAN.js is a full-stack containing Angular - it is not some separate thing.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, but I wonder if there is some similar mean "package" that implements controller as syntax :)

Comment: `Controller As` is an Angular feature, not a MEAN feature. MongoDB, Express, and Node.js have no part in what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, but do you know any mean framework (such as mean.js) that implements controller as in the angular part?

Comment: No? There is a whole slew of Javascript frontend frameworks... Also mean is not a adjective for the framework, it is an acronym. The `Controller As` syntax is up to the developer to implement, so whether you use the MEAN stack or any other Web Framework with Angular, you can use it.

Comment: There is [CEAN.js](http://www.ceanjs.org/), but they just replace MongoDB with Couchbase.

Comment: Ok thanks for that info.